# u-boot doesn't detect my Ethernet over USB interface (no tftp request)

Tags: raspbian, u-boot

I'm trying to get a flashing station up and running on a Raspberry Pi using Raspbian Jessie (latest stable release, Kernel Version 4.4).

However, I want to make use of the four USB ports, and to do so, I'll be using Ethernet over USB (since u-boot uses Ethernet to check the tftp server).

## Pre-requisites and configuration

Here is the things I installed on the Raspberry Pi :

- isc-dhcp-server
- xinetd

I configured several files :

#### `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
log-facility local7;
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
{
  range dynamic-bootp 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.100;
  if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 10) = "AM335x ROM"
  {
    filename "u-boot-spl-restore.bin";
  }
  elsif substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 17) = "AM335x U-Boot SPL"
  {
    filename "u-boot-restore.img";
  }
  else
  {
    filename "zImage";
  }

  range 192.168.2.101 192.168.2.199;
}
```

The four first lines being there by default.

#### `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp`

```
service tftp
{
  socket_type = dgram
  protocol = udp
  wait = yes
  user = root
  server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
  server_args = -s /tftpboot
  disable = no
}
```

This file didn't exist, so I had to create it. It's included like other services by `/etc/xinetd.conf`.

#### `/tftpboot/`

Created this folder, executed these commands on it :

- `sudo cp /path/to/boot/files/* /tftpboot/`
- `sudo chmod -R 777 /tftpboot/`
- `sudo chown -R nobody:nogroup /tftpboot`

#### `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

Added `usb0` to the list of interfaces :

```
INTERFACES="usb0"
```

#### `/etc/network/interfaces`

Created an interface for `usb0` :

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    network 192.168.2.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    up /etc/network/if-up.d/usb-interfaces
```

#### `/etc/network/if-up.d/usb-interfaces`

Created the following script, referenced by `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = usb0 ]; then
    sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
fi
```

#### Restart all the services!

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tftp-hpa restart
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

## Tests and results

Let's call the Raspberry Pi the **host** and the linux I want to flash the **target**.

So, for this, I had all the logs on the host, and had a serial console on the target (which means that I can access the boot logs from the kernel).

What happens basically :

- From the target's PoV : nothing in particular displays on the serial log. It just blocks for a bit then boots, normally.
- From the host's PoV : [here is the complete log.](https://gist.github.com/Neph0/b923bd42bcea4fe1bbf22b95478ac21d) It stops after the `usb0` interface disappears, when the Linux system starts booting. As you can see, there is a `BOOTREQUEST` followed immediately by a `BOOTREPLY`. At this point, the target knows the name of the file it must get from the `tftp` server (specified in the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file), so a `tftp` request should follow... But nothing happens.

I've tested the `tftp` server running on the Raspberry Pi both from the target and from my computer, and in both cases, I can get the files correctly. I also tried with different files, and was able to confirm that the files used (inside of my `/tftpboot/` folder) are correct and functional.

What I thought about and tested :

- **The power supplied by the Raspberry Pi's USB ports isn't enough.** Tested through a USB 2.0 independently-powered hub, results were exactly the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a complete log from the target console as well, thanks!

Comment: @TomRini, [Here is the log.](https://gist.github.com/Neph0/44d58b39bf92a9117168f6ab767d8f9a) As you can see, it boots from the NAND, doesn't do anything with TFTP.

Comment: yes, with the log it's clear that it's not even trying network, and I assume that this means you didn't change anything in the U-Boot environment in order to have it try and use network?  I don't see anything in the above post indicating as such and there's lots of general information on how to network boot in U-Boot elsewhere.

Comment: @TomRini, the U-boot from the target is correctly configured to try a network boot when possible. We actually got it to work by changing exactly the same files and using the same applications on a Ubuntu 12. But this issue is still open since we'd really like to get it to run on the rasp pi.

Comment: your U-Boot log is showing that it's not trying to do any sort of network commands at all.  You're implying via the dhcp fragment that both SPL and U-Boot self are loading via network and your host log shows that only.  In fact, what is confusing here now is that 'usb0' (per your syslog) is _not_ a USB-Ethernet adapter, but the am335x bringing up a USB Gadget interface as ethernet to your RPi.

Comment: @TomRini, what are you suggesting? That the usb0 interface comes up only because of the am335x, my prior configuration doesn't have anything to do with it? I'm kinda lost

Comment: I'm saying that at least in part your problem description is not clear.  The logs that you post do not show U-Boot attempting any sort of networking whatsoever.  You need to start debugging within U-Boot to see what commands are and are not run.  I suspect that yes, you are only seeing the usb0 come up as the ROM request.  Everything in your U-Boot log shows that it is not trying to do anything network related.

Comment: @TomRini indeed. What's annoying is that when u-boot successfully starts in TFTP mode, it doesn't print anything either, it just starts in TFTP mode right away. With the RPi, it seems like it tried to boot in TFTP mode but eventually goes back to booting regularly from the NAND. Some guy on IRC told me that it could be because of the PXE protocole not being the same at each endpoint, and u-boot just gives up and boots regularly. But I wasn't able to confirm this claim because of the lack of logs...

Comment: right, that lack of logs is why I keep saying U-Boot is not trying to use the network, and you're only seeing requests from the ROM.  U-Boot is not silent about trying any of this stuff.  I would strongly encourage you to interrupt the boot process on the target and do a 'printenv'.

Comment: @TomRini thanks for the suggestion, I will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was that there were several TFTP servers running on my system, and I wasn't configuring the correct one.

To anyone with this issue, I suggest running a command similar to `ps ax | grep tftp`. It will often also tell you which directory is used as the root for the TFTP server.